# Can't achive a part of json encoded data

Tags: jquery, json

I have this response:

{"status":"succes","message":"Some message!"}

All the data.status or data.message is undefinied...

```
success  : function (data, status)
     {

        console.log(data);
        if(data.status=='error'){
            console.log(data.message);
            //$('p.file_error').html(data.message);
        }else {

            console.log(data.message);
        }


     }
```

My controller has something like this:

```
$data['status']='error';
$data['message']='Some message!';
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Then `data` is probably still a string. You have to parse the JSON into object/arrays or let jQuery do it automatically for you.

Comment: You don't want to check for errors inside a `success` callback: use proper HTTP statuses, and use `jQuery.fail` or `jQuery.done` accordingly. If you are using a 3rd party API wrapping errors inside plain 200 responses, consider pointing this out to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have something like this, I think you're missing the dataType value should be with the type "json" to works properly.

```
$.ajax({
            url : base_url() + '/controller/method',
            data : {param1: 'val1', "param2" : val2},
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
```